# C# - converting string with decimals to integer

Tags: c#, string, integer

I have a string 
"1.0.0.1";

I want to convert this string to numeric values = 1001;

how do i do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way would be to strip out the periods and parse:

```
var input = "1.0.0.1";
int number = int.Parse(input.Replace(".", ""));
```

Note - this version will throw an exception if the string is not a number once the periods are stripped out. If you don't want this behaviour, you can use `int.TryParse`

```
var input = "1.0.0.1";
int number;

int.TryParse(input.Replace(".", ""), out number);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try

```
int.Parse(myString.Replace(".", ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Int32 num;
    String numString = "1.0.0.1";

    Boolean success = Int32.TryParse(numString.Replace(".",""), out num);
```

Then you can test that success is true before attempting to use the num integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
        string number = "1.0.1.0.1";
        var convertedString = int.Parse(number.Replace(".",""));
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

if your string is static

```
 int number = Convert.ToInt32("1.0.0.1".Replace(".", ""));
```

else

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32(yourstringvariable.Replace(".", ""));
```